# Can a Firestore publisher detect subscriptions from listeners?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Can a Firestore client detect subscriptions to a document? I want a client to only publish (write) document changes if at least one other client is listening to that document. In my case, this would dramatically reduce the number of Firestore writes across the database.

Scenario:

- a client is sampling a measured value every 3 seconds and publishing this to Firestore
- another client (an app) is listening to this Firestore document and displaying the value updates
- the app is only open on occasion, when the user wants to view the data. Most of the time it is not open, and thus no clients are listening to that document

Is there any way in the Firestore API to detect if a document is being listened to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not possible.  Code that writes a document will do so unconditionally.  You can't arrange for a write to happen if there are no listeners, and you can't find out if there are any listeners at all.  You will need some other (much more complex system) set up to do something like that.

Answer (score 0):

As Doug said, there is nothing built in to Firestore to detect whether there are listeners on the data. The closest I can think of is the [presence system](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-presence) that is (sort of) built into Firebase's other database (Realtime Database), but that doesn't exist on Firestore (yet, an Extension is in the works for it).

But even on that you'd probably need to do some extra work, to track specifically what collection(s) each client is listening to. It'd boil down to:

1. When attaching an observer, also record that observer in the Realtime Database. At the same time register an `onDisconnect` handler for this node, so that it automatically gets deleted when the client disconnects.
2. When detaching an obersver, remove its record from the Realtime Database and remove the `onDisconnect` handler.
3. Now in your publisher app, you can detect how many observers there are to each collection.